# Stacking QPushButtons on the other side of a QMenuBar

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8, qpushbutton, qmenubar

I want to stack some `QPushButton` objects on the other side of my `QMenuBar`.

This is how my window looks now:
[image: how it looks]

And this is how I want it to look like (I've photoshopped the image):
[image: how i want it to look]

I know that in the `motif` widget style, the help menu is aligned to the right, but I'm sticking with `plastique`, so it's not a problem for me.

I'm using Qt4.8. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe don't use a menubar but a toolbar with text-only buttons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

QMenuBar has a [`setCornerWidget`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmenubar.html#setCornerWidget) function, that sets a widget (that may include a whole layout) as the cornet widget.

Answer (score 3):

`QMainWindow::setMenuWidget()` can be used to set any widget as the main window's menu bar widget. Using an appropriate layout, you can use something like the following to customize the menu bar (`MainWindowImpl` is a sub class of `QMainWindow`):

```
void MainWindowImpl::setupMenubar() {
    QWidget* menuWidget = new QWidget(this);

    QGridLayout* menuWidgetLayout = new QGridLayout(menuWidget);
    menuWidget->setLayout(menuWidgetLayout);

    // Add the menu bar and all tool buttons to the widget
    menuWidgetLayout->addWidget(theMenubar, 0, 0, 1,1);
    menuWidgetLayout->addWidget(new QToolButton(), 0, 1, 1, 1);
    menuWidgetLayout->addWidget(new QToolButton(), 0, 2, 1, 1);

    // set the custom widget as the main window's menu widget
    setMenuWidget(menuWidget);
}
```

`theMenubar` points to the `QMenuBar` which contains your application's main menu bar.

Comment: Great, did not know about that one - I used my approach earlier when I wanted to add some buttons inside the menu area, but **below** the menu items. Your approach is indeed much simpler when the buttons should be to the right or to the left of the menu items. Accept your own answer, I think you can earn a badge :)