# How to set buttons in QMenuBar at right corner in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmenubar

I need to add two buttons at right side of QMenuBar (in left usual menu items) and change it icons time by time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to add two buttons at right side of QMenuBar (in left usual menu items)

This question might have an answer on how to add the buttons to the right side of a menu bar:
[Stacking QPushButtons on the other side of a QMenuBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645596/stacking-qpushbuttons-on-the-other-side-of-a-qmenubar).

> and change it icons time by time

You can use a [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) to trigger a slot periodically. Inside the slot, use [QPushBtton::setIcon()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#icon-prop) to change the icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "layout direction" :

```
QMainWindow mainW;
mainW.show();
QMenuBar* menu = new QMenuBar();
menu->addAction( "action 1" );
menu->addAction( "action 2" );
mainW.setMenuBar( menu );
menu->setLayoutDirection( Qt::RightToLeft); // Display menu bar to the right
```