# How do I create a custom window title bar using PyQt4?

Tags: python, css, user-interface, pyqt4

I am finding a way to customize my window title bar for my `PyQt4` application. As far as I understand, It  is not possible to use `Style-sheet` for this purpose. Instead I have to hide the title bar with

```
.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

and implement my own title bar. This is where I am puzzled as I have seen someone did use a `QHboxlayout` with `QLabel`(for window title name) and `QButton`(for exit,max,min actions) to make one like this

[image]

And he used `Style-Sheets` to decorate each individual widgets. That's probably fine for a simple title bar. But what if I want more complicated title bar like this?

[image]

I don't think just by altering `Style-Sheets` properties will give me this kind of looks.

So,my question is, is it possible to create such a complicated title bar in `PyQt4`? If so, as a beginner, what should I be looking at? I will dig and learn the concept by myself, I just needs some directions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am too late in replying, but anyway, I'll just let you know a few thing I have pickup myself. For one, it is quite easy to create such a "complicated" title bar, and UI using PyQt4. I would recommend you to read this post

[Stacking QPushButtons on the other side of a QMenuBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645596/stacking-qpushbuttons-on-the-other-side-of-a-qmenubar)

The UI for the max/min/close buttons may be achieved using style sheets - you'll have to tinker with it a fair amount. If you have trouble adapting the code from Qt4 to PyQt4 you can mail me, I'll do my best to help you.

Comment: I would as well like to add that you may subclass QMainWindow, and QMenubar to perhaps obtain the exact configuration and paint the extra details. Its a lot of work and quite tedious. The method in the above post is quite clean.